# exception message not working

Tags: c#, exception

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            string[] names = new string[2];
            string g = names[2];
        }
        catch(Exception error) {
            MessageBox.Show(error);
        }
    }
}
```

I don't know whats wrong with it cant seem to find the error. It would helpful if you could help me?

Comment: Exactly what result are you seeing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no overload of [`Show`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.messagebox.show%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which accepts an `Exception` as a parameter. You probably want to show the exception's [`Message`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.exception.message%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property:

```
try
{
    string[] names = new string[2];
    string g = names[2];
}
catch(Exception error) 
{
    MessageBox.Show(error.Message);
}

// Index was outside the bounds of the array.
```

Or possibly call [`ToString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.exception.tostring%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), which will typically provide you with a little more information than just the `Message`:

```
try
{
    string[] names = new string[2];
    string g = names[2];
}
catch(Exception error) 
{
    MessageBox.Show(error.ToString());
}

// System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array.
//   at Form1.button1_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in  ...Form1.cs:line 35
```

Answer (score 0):

you can not access `index 2` as index starts from 0

```
string g = names[2];//index2 is invalid
```

you can use ToString() to get all exception details

```
 catch(Exception error) {
        MessageBox.Show(error.ToString());
    }
```